# What is the best way to compare the similarity of two strings?

Tags: ruby

All these strings refer to the same movie. How can I compare them to check the similarity?

I get all these strings from an external source:

- Spider man
- Spider-man
- Spider man 1
- SpiderMan
- Spider - Man
- Film: Spider-man
- Film:Spiderman

  For me, `"Spider man 1"` and `"Spider man 2"` are two strings completely different than `"spider-man"` and `"spider man"`.

I'd want a function that, if it compare all these strings, it will return "true"

Comment: I think this question could use some clarification. Are you asking "Does an algorithm exist that will tell me these refer to the same object" or "What algorithm could tell me which of these strings are most similar to one another"?

Comment: Do you want a statistical answer or boolean? You could get pretty close with stripping whitespace/punctuation, lower-casing and checking if one contains another.

Comment: Show us some code you've written to solve the problem, or that demonstrates the problem you're seeing. Also, how do you have a series of strings that refer to the same object? Strings are objects in Ruby, so each would point to a different variable slot.

Comment: Ok, i've updatede my question post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Smith-Waterman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) can give you some points.

Answer (score 1):

Use Smith-Waterman algorithm or other string similarity algorithm. One possibility would be using [FuzzBall](https://github.com/vincentchu/fuzz_ball).

```
require 'fuzz_ball'
THRESHOLD_SCORE = 0.75
MATCHER = FuzzBall::Searcher.new [ 'Spider man' ]

def complies?( str )
  matchdata = MATCHER.search str
  return false if matchdata.nil? or matchdata.empty?
  score = matchdata[0][:score]
  puts "score is #{score}"
  score > THRESHOLD_SCORE
end

complies? 'man spider'
#=> score is 0.8
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) can calculate how many changes you need to convert one string into another.

Comment: :))) well the first page link when Googling string similarity is Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metrics :))). 3k users need to do more than pointing this out :)))

Comment: Yes, i know it but I need something stricter. For me, "Spider man 1" and "Spider man 2" are two string completely different that "spider-man" and "spider man"

Comment: @user1028100 you should define the comparison criteria first and only then ask for an algorithm. personally, i don't understand why you consider 'Spider Man 1' and 'spider man' being different despite referring to the (obviously) same object.